# "method" + "of" + "doing something"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

He popularized a method of releasing from bad eating habits.

is this correct? I am not sure about the connection "method" with "of"

Comment: *Method of* is fine, but *release* is a transitive verb. You probably mean *losing bad habits* or *getting rid of bad habits*.

Comment: Here is an alternative - He came up with a method to help people come off their bad habits.

Comment: Can I use " give up" instead of come off?

Answer (score 1):

As StoneyB says, *release* is a transitive verb and thus it requires a direct object. This could have been correct if you'd have written...

> He popularized a method of releasing *(someone)* from bad eating habits.

But that's not the case.

And hence, you can change the sentence -

> He popularized a method of getting rid of bad habits

That's just one of the ways to tell that though.